# Managing related Models in Rails with React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, separation-of-concerns

I have the following data relations:

```
NewsfeedItem.rb
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes

Like.rb
  belongs_to :newsfeed_item

Comment.rb
  belongs_to :newsfeed_item
```

In html.erb files, managing these relations was easy. For example:

```
# in newsfeed_items/index.hmtl.erb
<% @newsfeed_items.each do |item| %>
  <div>

    <div>
      <h2><%= item.title %></h2>
      <p><%= item.content %></p>
    </div>

    <p>Likes: <%= item.likes.length %></p>

    <ul>
      <% item.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <li><%= comment.text %></li>
      <% end # comments.each %>
   </ul>

  </div>
<% end # newsfeed_items.each%>
```

However, I'm struggling with how to properly separate concerns when I want to extrapolate this into React. Current newsfeed_items component:

```
# in components/newsfeed_items.jsx
var NewsfeedItems = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: []};
  },
  loadItems: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET', 
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({items: data});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }, 
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadItems();
  },
  render: function() {
    var items = this.state.data.map(function(item) {
      return (<NewsfeedItem key={item.id} title={item.title} content={item.content} />
    });
    return (
      <div className="c-newsfeed-list">
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This component retrieves items from the `newsfeed_items_controller`:

```
# in newsfeed_items_controller.rb
def index
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @newsfeed_items}
  end
end
```

It seems like I'd be mixing concerns if I attached the `likes` and `comments` of the `newsfeed_items` to the json returned from `newsfeed_items_path`. Yet, setting separate ajax calls for each `newsfeed_item` to GET its correlating `likes` and `comments` seems unnecessary.

Which is best practice / best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that multiple API calls are unnecessary. Here are two alternatives I have used in production:

1. [JSON Builder Gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) This allows you to pass customized associated objects along with your main object through an API
2. Overwrite the `as_json` method within the model to incorporate your associated objects. By default `render json: @newsfeed_items` calls `@newsfeed_items.to_json` so by overwriting the method to include it's associations, you can get whatever you want.

Comment: Think I'll definitely go the jBuilder route. Thanks!